# Google Sheets script to find text in a range

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find a script that will search a range ("B29:B28") for a string.  The string will come from a variable, lets call it value.  I will also be copying this, but for now lets just select it.

So:

```
function findText() {
  find(value in range("B29:B28")
  make cell containing text active
}
```

Obviously this code is just what I want, not any type of code.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Best practice or not, this works:

```
  var rng = sheet.getRange(28, 2, 11, 1);
  var data = rng.getValues();
  var search = "What to search for"

  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == activeBill) {
      data[i][0] = "Sets found cell to this";
      rng.setValues(data);
    } 
  }
```